# requestAnimationFrame Not Being Triggered in iOS

Tags: ios, safari, requestanimationframe

I have an application that uses a webview with some javascript code that runs inside of it.
There, I am using **requestAnimationFrame** when performing some logic.

This application has been running for several years with no issues, until recently.

What I noticed was that, for some reason, only on iOS (Safari), even though the logic gets to the lines associated with requestAnimationFrame, the callback I pass to it, never gets called.

This code has been working fine for the past couple of years and I have not changed anything there.

Has anyone experienced this kind of issue?
Could it be related to any changes made in Safari?

***Note***

I am not sharing any code since the call to requestAnimationFrame is pretty standard and I am not running any animation there per se.

I.E.

```
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        //Logic here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Don't know why it happened. My solution right now is overwriting the requestAnimationFrame

```
var lastTime = 0;
window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
  var now = window.performance.now();
  var nextTime = Math.max(lastTime + 16, now); //First time will execute it immediately but barely noticeable and performance is gained.
  return setTimeout(function() { callback(lastTime = nextTime); }, nextTime - now);
};
window.cancelAnimationFrame = clearTimeout;
```

Or you can add more conditions to this polyfill https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671?permalink_comment_id=2976376#gistcomment-2976376